# Is it possible to consume events in kafka from custom keycloak spi

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I was exploring on side like whether create realm action can be done via event architecture flow.

ie. If a service publish a create realm event to a kafka topic
A custom keycloak SPI provider should listen to the topic from kafka
Up on receiving realm creation event it need to create a realm in keycloak

Is that possible to listen continuously to a kafka topic from keycloak spi?

Comment: Why you don't listen continuously to a kafka topic in your own app and then just use Keycloak Admin API to create realm?

Comment: The create realm api consume more than 1 min to serve request when number of realm increases